# Telling exim that "no recipients found" isn't panic-worthy

Tags: exim

I manage several Debian servers which all use exim4 as their MTA and, for the most part, everything is happy.

However, one of them has a web application on it which sends out notices, and some of the potential recipients are not set up properly/completely, resulting in the web application apparently trying to send mail with no recipients.  Exim then writes this to paniclog, which in turn causes me to get mail every day warning that the "mail system might be broken", even though an empty recipient list means the *sending application* is broken, not the MTA.

Is is possible to configure exim to treat this as a normal failure (bounce the mail and write an error report to mainlog and/or syslog) instead of creating a paniclog for it?  If not, is there any other solution which doesn't involve a daily cron job deleting paniclog before the "does paniclog exist?" check runs (which would carry the risk of hiding *actual* problems with the mail system)?

Note that, while fixing the web application which sends the offending mail would be the optimal solution, I'm not responsible for that application, so it's not really an option.  I have notified the developers who are responsible for it, but that's as much as I'm able to do on that side.